# Difference dates between two diferentes dates with different format

Tags: swift, xcode

I get date from a device, the user has to enter year (YY) and months(MM) and I have to compare it with the date from device but for example if user enter in year 20 and in months 11  and the date from device(DD-MM-YYYY) is it 19/06/2020
I separated the date with substringC and did the diff but what can I do when the month is negative?

```
      let fechaAnt = karpayValue.getFecha()
        print(fechaAnt)
        let numero = fechaAnt.count
        print(numero)
        let subCadenaTX1 = String(fechaAnt.substringC(from: 0, to:2))
        let subCadenaTX2 = String(fechaAnt.substringC(from: 3, to:5))
        let subCadenaTX3 = String(fechaAnt.substringC(from: 6, to:10))

        print(subCadenaTX1)
        print(subCadenaTX2)
        print(subCadenaTX3)
        let año = Int(subCadenaTX3)
        let mes = Int(subCadenaTX2)

        let  totalAños =  año! - 20
        let  totalMeses = mes! - 11

        print(totalAños)
        print(totalMeses)
```

Comment: If you need to perform calendric calculations, you could have a look at `[NS]Calendar` (calculate) & `[NS]DateFormatter` (convert between dates/strings).

Comment: It's not clear to me why months (or years) can not be negative?